# Is there a modern ( e.g. CLR ) replacement for bison / yacc?

Tags: bison

I have just been re-working an old bit of compiler-like code written using bison. While I was doing this, I was wondering what the modern equivalent is? Is there a nice .NET ( or similar ) compiler writing framework that takes a BNF grammar and splits out a DLL that does the parsing?

Comment: You can use ANTLR as pointed to by others but I don't see the problem with Bison. Besides it's still actively maintained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Gardens Point GPPG and GPLEX in my own dynamic language interpreter. GPPG and GPLEX have been adopted by Microsoft as MPPG and MPLEX in the Visual Studio 200x SDK. This means that is very easy to create a Visual Studio language extension for syntax colouring of your language.

Answer (score 6):

There's also [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org), a very widely used parser generator implemented in Java.

Comment: ..which btw supports C# as a target.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Gardens Point Parser Generator.  It's a YACC/BISON like implementation for C#

[GPPG](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gppg/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Coco/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/). It's very similar to JavaCC. Supports C#, Java, C++, F#, VB.Net, Oberon, and other languages.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search found the [Gardens Point Parser Generator](http://plas.fit.qut.edu.au/gppg/).